# how to setup the domain like as projectid.appspot.com in local app engine java dev server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud-platform

I have a appengine-java-sdk1.9.34. I can to run app engine java project  at a time one project in this app engine development server.

I need to run apps like appid.appspot.com. How to configure the appengine java sdk in local machine? And how to configure the customized local server as cloud platform with local domain(appid.appspot.com).

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way will be to setup such hostname in */etc/hosts*.

For Unix and MacOS it's located in `/etc/hosts`, and on Windows at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. Just add following into this file:

```
127.0.0.1 appid.appspot.com
```

And also you probably need to use port 80 instead of default 8080.